# Are their drivers for the Apple Keyboard in Windows 7 64bit?(Bonus point: Where's Print Screen?)

Tags: keyboard, windows

I am using the official wired Apple Keyboard with my Windows 7 64bit Desktop, is there a source for official drivers anywhere?

I'm kinda fine with the default setup, but I'd really like the ability to printscreen! I am in the UK, but wouldn't mind switching language if that makes all the keys work in he right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a Apple Keyboard on W7 Daily.

The key thing is to use a utility that lets you remap the keys.

Personally, I use a little utility called [KeyTweak](http://majorgeeks.com/KeyTweak_d4161.html) (It's Free!), but there are lots of other alternatives.

This lets you set unused keys to whatever you want - I have F13 set as print-screen, and F14-F19 set as media playback keys (play, pause, etc).
It can also let you fix the windows/alt keys so they are in the correct place, if that bothers you.

<sup>There are a couple of caveats, namely I have yet to find anything that lets you make use of the "fn" and eject keys. However, the additional (unused) F13-F19 keys compensate for that.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can find the drivers in the Mac OS X Install DVD (if you have it) at `\Boot Camp\Drivers\Apple\x64\AppleKeyboardInstaller64.exe`.

If you do not have the DVD, you will have to remap the keys, as mentioned in Fake Name's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15921/are-their-drivers-for-the-apple-keyboard-in-windows-7-64bitbonus-point-wheres/15925#15925).

To take a print screen (with the drivers installed), press <kbd>F13</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: Where can I download the Boot Camp drivers?

Comment: You can't download it.

Comment: Where there's a will there's a way...

Comment: You can try to borrow the DVD from someone who owns a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

This post help me to get the keyboard driver working:
[Apple Keyboard driver for Windows](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/45140-apple-keyboard-driver-for-windows/page-6#entry1763336)